# Sails JS ignore controller

Tags: sails.js

Sails JS v1.0.1

I generate simple API by using `sails generate api articles`, and use blueprints to fill db. Next I updated my model. But when I started to fill my controller somethings went wrong. Here is my controller:

```
/**
 * ArticlesController
 *
 * @description :: Server-side actions for handling incoming requests.
 * @help        :: See https://sailsjs.com/docs/concepts/actions
 */

module.exports = {
  list: function (req, res) {
    sails.log.debug('Im inside list!');
    return res.view('list');
  },
  add: function (req, res) {
    sails.log.debug('Im inside add!');
    return res.view('../pages/add');
  },
};
```

I can get all blueprints as json in `/articles` but `/articles/list`and  `/articles/add` show 404 page. Even dont know how to debug. Thanks!

upd. I added them to routes and all works fine.

```
'get /articles/list': 'ArticlesController.list',
'get /articles/add': 'ArticlesController.add',
```

But is it true way to do this??? Why all my routes not compile automatically when I did `sails generate api articles`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable `sails.config.blueprints.actions`, you can find it in `config/blueprints` and set `actions` to `true`.